# How to check Twilio blocked number list

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

> When Twilio receives an Opt-out keyword from one of your users, it
> adds this phone number to a list of blocked numbers. Twilio checks
> this list before sending any future outgoing messages.

Is there a place to find this blocked number list in the Twilio console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not. You must keep track of the opt-out list yourself. Twilio will forward the opt-out keywords to your application to handle this.

[Twilio support for opt-out keywords (SMS STOP filtering)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-)

Using Advanced Opt-out (Which require a messaging service)

[Keeping track of your users' status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/tutorials/advanced-opt-out#keeping-track-of-your-users-status)